# Add a custom field to an Article type for knowledge articles

Tags: knowledge, articles

How to add a new custom field to an article type in salesforce. I am using the developer edition of Salesforce. I navigate to `Customize -> Knowledge -> Article Types`. When I click on 'edit' for an already created article type. I do not see any option for creating a new custom field for the article. [image]

Comment: Article Type is like a custom object. Don't click on edit but click on the article type itself, the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are navigating to wrong side:

Go to `Customize -> Knowledge -> Article Types | Click on Article Type Name`

You should be on a screen like this:

[image: Article Type]
In field section you can create new Fields.